# method not allowed exception in postman

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am writing API login register system for my app.
I have created a controller for login and register, so I can create my user from postmen and log in from there but when I try to call `my get details` method it's returning

> as a method not allowed an exception

here is my Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Validator;
class PassportController extends Controller
{
//
  public $successStatus = 200;


  public function register(Request $request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
        'c_password' => 'required|same:password',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
                return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);            
            }
    $input = $request->all();
    $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);
    $user = User::create($input);

    $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
    $success['name'] =  $user->name;
    return response()->json(['success'=>$success], $this->successStatus);
}

public function login(){
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){

        $user = Auth::user();
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
    }
    else{
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
    }
}


public function getDetails()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    return response()->json(['success' => $user], $this->successStatus);
}
}
```

*api.php*

```
 <?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('register', 'API\PassportController@register')->name('register');
Route::post('login', 'API\PassportController@login')->name('login');



Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
 Route::post('details', 'API\PassportController@getDetails');
});
```

here is my postmen screenshot

[image]

you can share me your thoughts or any ideas

Comment: Could you please remove the indentation of the starting PHP tag `<?php`? and recheck because it sometimes causes problems.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd i tried but its giving error like page not found

Comment: @PranavMandlik: getDetails() use only authenticate users right?

Comment: yes its for authenticated users only

Comment: @PranavMandlik: Please put your route outside of [auth:api] (i.e Route::post('details', 'API\PassportController@getDetails');) and check

Comment: getting same error dont know whats the problem

Comment: @PranavMandlik: Please project run on artisan and check (i.e php artisan serv)

Answer (score 3):

Are you using passport with laravel? If yes there might be multiple issues causing this.

I would like to see what you get when you click on application frames, but here are some of the more common issues i found myself dealing with

General issues I know of (regardless of technology)

1. method is not public
2. Authorization and Accept should be in table Headers in postman [image]

when using the Authorization it need to be like this: Headers tab

key: Authorization
Value: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiI

where this gibberish is your access token without any commas

3. check you server and laravel logs. Sometimes postman messes up and send get instead of post requests and the other way around
4. If you get Unauthenticated error

4.1 follow these steps here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport

4.2 copy the client secret from the db/command line

4.3 use this endpoint in the picture [image]
{{url_key}} id the address to my site ex: demo.dev or htttp://localhost. I'm not sure about using locahost (I only developed laravel on vagrant so i don't know what issues may arise from that)
Headers should be empty in this case

4.4 use the token to authenticate

5. Make sure VerifyCsrfToken class looks like this

> ```
>  class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
>     {
>         /**
>          * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
>          *
>          * @var array
>          */
>         protected $except = [
>             'api/*'
>         ];
>     }
> ```

Comment: i tried to send from header then its giving me message like {"message":"Unauthenticated."}

Comment: do you have any idea over this msg

Comment: yeah. that's normal. You need to login. You need and endpoint like get token where you login. I will attach a photo right away of how it should look. Did you do php artisan passport:install  and php artisan passport:keys (follow this to get started)

Comment: when i tried its giving error like {"error":"invalid_client","message":"Client authentication failed"}

Comment: so then how i call api/details url ?

Comment: yeah. using that token in headers like in the first picture

Comment: which token i have to use

Comment: is it from generated after login?

Comment: access_token. you need refresh_token in mobile apps sometimes. I updated my reponse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167343/discussion-between-indra-and-pranav-mandlik).

Answer (score 2):

Please add your function url in app->http->Middleware->VerifyCsrfToken in $except .

laravel need csrf . if you pass data from outside it will not pass csrf so at that time you have to define for this function no csrf required .

Comment: can you please share csrf controller code and web.php code . @PranavMandlik

Answer (score 2):

You method is `getDetails()` while your route is `post`

```
Route::post('details', 'API\PassportController@getDetails');
```

Try changing `getDetails()` to `postDetails()`
and change route as

```
Route::post('details', 'API\PassportController@postDetails');
```

Comment: Still getting the same error? Also why are you using get and post together?  @PranavMandlik

Comment: What error do you get when you change `getDetails()` to `postDetails()` and changing the route? Please share @PranavMandlik

Comment: Also your route clearly shows `Route::post` for `getDetails()`

Comment: its just the function name get and post not depend on that its depend on Route::post or Route::get

Comment: I tried the same code and I receive 
`NotFoundHttpException` for the same case using `post` route for a `get `function